# Parsing Message-ID header returned by imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib, email-headers

I'm fetching the messageid from emails in Gmail via IMAP.

This code:

```
messageid = m.fetch(num, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)])')
print messageid
```

returns this:

```
[('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)] {78}', 'Message-ID: <actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>\r\n\r\n'), ')']
```

How would I parse just the actual message-id out of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also achieve what you want using the [`email` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html)'s [`HeaderParser.parsestr()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#parser-class-api) (*same API as Parser but doesn't worry about the email's body*) and the [`parseaddr()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr).

```
>>> from email.parser import HeaderParser
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr

>>> hp = HeaderParser()

>>> response = [('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)] {78}',
                 'Message-ID: <actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>\r\n\r\n'), ')']

>>> header_string = response[0][1]

>>> header_string
'Message-ID: <actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>\r\n\r\n'

>>> header = hp.parsestr(header_string)

>>> header
<email.message.Message instance at 0x023A6198>

>>> header['message-id']
'<actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>'

>>> msg_id = parseaddr(header['message-id'])

>>> msg_id
('', 'actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com')

>>> msg_id[1]
'actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com'
```

**Thus:**

```
from email.parser import HeaderParser
from email.utils import parseaddr

hp = HeaderParser()

def get_id(response):
    header_string = response[0][1]
    header = hp.parsestr(header_string)
    return parseaddr(header['message-id'])[1]

response = [('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)] {78}',
             'Message-ID: <actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>\r\n\r\n'), ')']


print(get_id(response))
```

**returns:**

```
actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC 1036, 822](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/1036.html#2.1.5):

> In order to conform to RFC-822, the
>   Message-ID must have the format:
>         <unique@full_domain_name>

So the actual message ID would be between < and > The domain part is part of the ID.

I'd probably *strip* the string, then *split* on the *<* character, verify it ends with *>* and then cut that off.

I can't really work out a good solution with your data (is there a typo in it at the end?), but if it looks like the following I'd parse it something like this

```
 # Note: my list does not end with , ")"]
 messageparts = [('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (MESSAGE-ID)] {78}', 
                  'Message-ID: <actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com>\r\n\r\n')]

 for envelope, data in messageparts:
        # data: the part with Message-ID in it
        # data.strip(): Newlines removed
        # .split("<"): Break in 2 parts, left of < and right of <. Removes <
        # .rstrip(">") remove > from the end of the line until there is 
        # no > there anymore;
        # "x>>>".rstrip() -> "x"
        print "The message ID is: ", data.strip().split("<")[1].rstrip(">")

    # Short alternative version:
    messageids = [data.strip().split("<")[1].rstrip(">") \
                  for env,data in messageparts]
    print messageids
```

Output:

```
The message ID is:  actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com
['actualmessageid@mail.mail.gmail.com']
```

I splitted some lines using '\' to make it a bit more readable here, and the code assumes the headers are all valid.

Comment: Yeah I want to have the message-ID in that format. But could you elaborate on how to strip/split the string?